# Node-multer: fails to uploade a file (cannot read property error)

Tags: node.js, forms, post, express, multer

I try to upload a file to a server using express.js and multer. I cannot get it work, even with a very simple code, it keeps displying the same error  :

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

I suspect I make some really stupid mistake, yet I cannot find out what's the problem. Thank you very much for your help !

index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File upload test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="uploadform" method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p><input type="file" name="img"></p>
            <p><input id="submit_upload" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and on the server side (server.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('img'), function (req, res) {
    //var form_description = req.body.description;
    console.log(req.files.name);
    //  insert operations into database get placed here
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "upload-example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A file upload example",
  "main": "server.js",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "~0.2.8",
    "express": "^3.2.6",
    "multer": "^1.1.0",
    "socket.io": "~0.9.14"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You [configure](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage) multer to accept single file, and single file will be stored in `req.file`.

2) Original filename stored in `req.file.originalname`.

3) Temp filename stored in `req.file.filename`.

Comment: Yes, it is file, not files, stupid error. Thanks again for the answer !